# Error in `recode()`: ! Argument 2 must be named

Tags: r, dplyr

```
table(Encuesta$genero)
Encuesta$sexo <- recode(Encuesta$genero, '"Mujer"=1 ; "Hombre"=0')
table(Encuesta$sexo)
```

this is the error:

```
Encuesta$sexo <- recode(Encuesta$genero,'"Mujer"=1 ; "Hombre"=0')
Error in `recode()`:
! Argument 2 must be named.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::recode(Encuesta$genero, "\"Mujer\"=1 ; \"Hombre\"=0")
 2. dplyr:::recode.character(Encuesta$genero, "\"Mujer\"=1 ; \"Hombre\"=0")
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which way you're trying to convert the data, but try one of the following:

```
Encuesta$sexo <- recode(Encuesta$genero, "1" = "Mujer", "0" = "Hombre")
Encuesta$sexo <- recode(Encuesta$genero, "Mujer" = 1, "Hombre" = 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the `'` in the end (from `"Hombre"=0'` ). It might work.

```
Encuesta$sexo <- recode(Encuesta$genero, "Mujer"=1 ; "Hombre"=0)
```